PowerBI API Rest API for updating the Datasource ID?
I have got an existing Power BI workspace where the Dataset is Snowflake Database in the background.
I wanted to update the existing connection to a new connection. See the settings screen below:

This basically means updating connection id in the above setting.
Power BI rest api has an API for updating datasource but it doesn't specify how can I update a connection ID.
Does anyone has any idea?
I have tried using this link with specifying new connection details in the Parameters but it doesn't update anything. Please provide examples if you have done anything similar.
